# Subtract two rows' values within the same column using Mysql group by ID

Tags: mysql, row, subtraction

I have a table as shown below. I want to do a partition and then subtract the values in the same column to get the difference.

Since there is no partition or equivalent function available in MySQL,
can anyone give me an idea of how to do it?
I have worked out the partition but not the other part.

```
SELECT ID,Date,
       @row_number:=CASE WHEN @ID=ID THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,
       @ID:=ID AS ID,value
FROM table1, (SELECT @row_number:=0,@ID:='') AS t 
ORDER BY id,Date;
```

Input:

```
 ID           Date        Value
1001    24-07-2017 09:43    10
1002    24-07-2017 09:43    11
1003    22-08-2017 21:42    10
1001    07-09-2017 20:33    11
1003    07-09-2017 20:33    44
1002    24-07-2017 09:43    55
1004    07-09-2017 20:33    66
```

Output should be:

```
rowno  ID         Date        Value Diff
1     1001  24-07-2017 09:43    10  N/A
2     1001  07-09-2017 20:33    11  1
1     1002  24-07-2017 09:43    11  N/A
2     1002  24-07-2017 09:43    55  44
1     1003  22-08-2017 21:42    10  n/A
2     1003  07-09-2017 20:33    44  34
1     1004  07-09-2017 20:33    66  N/A
```

Comment: What is your query supposed to be doing?  It is not obvious from your data.

Comment: What if you have three records per `ID`? How is the subtraction performed in this case?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Read the documentation re updating & reading the same variable in a query: it's undefined. You can google stackoverflow with a comment by me to see that for *current implementation code* there's a safe use involving CASE found by Percona.

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are incorrect. When you order by this column, you order by day first. Proper ordering is year-month-day. Use the proper datatype, datetime or timestamp. To do this you can do the following:

```
alter table table1 add column d datetime;
update table1 set d = str_to_date(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i');
alter table table1 drop column `Date`;
```

The query to get your desired result is then:

```
SELECT ID, d, Value,
       IF(@ID=ID, Value - @prevV, 'N/A') AS diff,
       @row_number:=CASE WHEN @ID=ID THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,

       @prevV := Value,
       @ID:=ID AS ID
FROM table1
, (SELECT @row_number:=0, @ID:='', @prevV := NULL) AS t 
ORDER BY id, d;
```

All you have to do is add another variable to hold the value of the previous row.

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/641955/2/0)
- here's [another sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/262d56f/1/0) to showcase what happens when you have 3 rows per ID

Comment: @Jithu Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept my answer :-)