# mysql group by year() of timestamp and foreign_id order by timestamp

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have a table like

```
create table `my_table`
(
  `id` int auto_increment primary key,
  `foreign_id` int not null,
  `some_data` text,
  `some_timestamp` timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null
);
```

I need to get unique rows both per year(got from timestap) and foreing_id , and get it from table ordered by timestamp

i've tried query :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM `my_table`
       ORDER BY `some_timestamp` DESC) as lr
GROUP BY YEAR(lr.`some_timestamp`),lr.`foreign_id`;
```

but this one not ordering by timestamp, idk why.

Other query worked ok untill i've loaded it to other server:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table`
WHERE `id`,`some_timestamp` IN
      (
       SELECT `id`,max(`some_timestamp`)
       FROM `my_table` lr2
       GROUP BY YEAR(lr2.`some_timestamp`),`lr2`.foreign_id
      );
```

on my pc this query executes around 3 seconds, on other server it get's error 504 gateway timeout.
Please help me to find best solution for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making things too complicated. It didn't order correctly because `GROUP BY` does an implicit sorting, when no `ORDER BY` is specified.

Simply do it like this:

```
SELECT some_timestamp, foreign_id, MAX(some_timestamp) AS most_recent_timestamp_per_year
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY YEAR(some_timestamp), foreign_id
ORDER BY `some_timestamp` DESC
```

I'm not sure, what your final query is supposed to do.

Also note, that you don't use `group by` correctly.
Every column in the select clause must either be specified in the group by clause or have an aggregate function applied to it. Otherwise you get random rows per group.

Comment: Thanks for answer, gonna read about group more, not really understand how it works.
Still your query is not what i'm looking for. I need to get rows with most recent date per year, like if i have 20-10-2017 and 21-10-2017 - it must get second one for sure. Thx again.

Comment: Yea, it's get's timestamp that i need, but `some_data` cell is still from row not ordered by timestamp

Comment: Have you seen that I added the `MAX(some_timestamp)` column? This should get what you want, unless the dates you have in your table really are in the format `21-10-2017`. Then your datatype is probably varchar or something, not date, datetime or timestamp. You'd have to adjust that. I've described this step in another answer today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926207/447489

Comment: No, it's timestamp for sure, just didnt saw your edit, look my 2nd comment pls

Comment: When you want other columns corresponding to min() or max() rows, you'd have to do it like this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Thx for answer, reworked my second query to JOIN format, , result is : SELECT l1.*
FROM `my_table` l1
  JOIN (
         SELECT `foreign_id`, MAX(`some_timestamp`) AS some_timestamp
         FROM `my_table`
         GROUP BY YEAR(`some_timestamp`),`foreign_id`) AS l2
    ON l1.foreign_id = l2.foreign_id AND l1.some_timestamp = l2.some_timestamp;
And it's works like i needed. Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

To order this query by date you need to rewrite it like this:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM `my_table`) as lr
GROUP BY YEAR(lr.`some_timestamp`),lr.`foreign_id`
ORDER BY YEAR(lr.`some_timestamp`) DESC;
```

About execution time for second query. 
If you don't want to dig in, try to add index on server DB to columns `some_timestamp` and `foreign_id`. It probably speed up the execution time.
Try something like this in mysql shell:
`CREATE INDEX my_request ON my_table (foreign_id, some_timestamp);

More about indexes you can find [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I dont need to order grouped data, i need to group ordered data.
I mean, i need to get most recent timestamp for each year
, have any solution?

Comment: @user8620109 you should look at what fancyPants wrote